# How to clear print area

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am new to macros.

I am trying to find a macro that will clear the print area on specified worksheets that do not have cell u1="x".  My workbook has over 80 worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Write this VBA code:

```
 Sub clearPrintAreas1()   
   Dim wks As Worksheet  

 For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets       
     If Not (wks.Range("u1") = "X") Then      
       wks.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""        
     End If  
   Next     
   Set wks = Nothing  
End Sub
```

PrintArea= "" will clear the print area and the code will test every sheet if U1 is not="X" then will clear the printarea of this sheet.

Comment: I'd recommend `FALSE` over `""`

Comment: @Raystafarian using `False` will throw an exception unfortunately.

Comment: @Brad it *shouldn't* - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-printarea-property-excel - but maybe it does for you.