# How to hide sheets that have cell u1=x

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

If I want to hide tabs that have u1=x, how would I do that? I have this but it is just hiding all pages instead of just the ones that have u1=x

```
Sub Hide_Sheets_Containing()
  Dim wks As Worksheet

  For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not (wks.Range("u1") = "X") Then
      wks.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
  Next
  Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you are hiding everything that does not have `X` in U1.  Remove the `Not` and make sure that you are looking for upper case X.  This is case sensitive.  to make it not case sensitive use `If (Ucase(wks.Range("u1")) = "X") Then`

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1063805/how-to-clear-print-area